# How do i make a folder like C:/"folder name" go to D:/"folder name" without changing the location. (Linking)

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, steam, folder-redirection

I had a folder at C:\Steam\steamapps\common\ that was located on to D:\Steam\steamapps\common.

So steam would download files in the C drive but the games would get installed on D.

I fixed this with a command in cmd, steam still thinks it is the same folder on C: but in reality the files where stored on D:.

When i updated windows the functionality whas gone, games started to install on the C drive and clicking the folder would open C:\Steam\steamapps\common\ instead of D:\Steam\steamapps\common.

I know i achieved to do this with one cmd command but i don't know what i did anymore, can anyone help me?

I'm not trying to change the download location but only the install, i want steam to use D instead of C but use C for downloading.

Comment: Instead of doing that, why not just make D your default install location for the games? That makes no sense that you want to "use C for downloading" and always store the game on D. You can also easily move games from one drive to another within the Steam application.

Comment: I don't know what commnd you used the first time, but an application called [Steam Mover](http://www.traynier.com/software/steammover) would do the linking and game moving for you. I used to use this before Steam supported moving games in their application.

Comment: "I fixed this with a command" - Please edit your question, to specify the exact command you used, your question cannot be answered without this relevant necessary information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this: 
`MKLINK /D "C:\Steam\steamapps\common" "D:\Steam\steamapps\common\"`
C:\Steam\steamapps now opens D:\Steam\steamapps
*I also linked the downloads from D to go to C just to be sure i won't screw up in the future.*

You can do this:
`MKLINK /D "Where to make the link" "Where the link goes to"`

[Got the info from here, easy to understand, be sure to read when doing this yourself.](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html)

> Syntax
>        MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] LinkName Target
>
> Key:
>
> /D     Create a Directory symbolic link. (default is file)
>
> /H     Create a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
>
> /J     Create a Directory Junction.
>
> LinkName The new symbolic link name.
>
> Target The path (relative or absolute) that the new link refers to.

This is useful since my C is a SSD and can keep up with my internet while my HDD (D) can't keep up, being the bottleneck. My games now download fast but still take time to install and decompress. This may seem useless for some but in my house internet(LAN) is only downstairs so when i have to download i won't be using my computer but with this, i can use my computer while steam is decompressing and installing. Also my SSD has a low capacity and my HDD has a terabyte so downloads are a great use for my SSD. Downloads get done and deleted using virtually no space while ill still get great speeds!